# Vectorizing logical operators in Excel

Tags: excel

Suppose I have two columns

A: (TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)

B: (TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

I want to do something like

`AND(A1:A3,B1:B3)` that returns (TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select, say, `C1:C3`, with selected cells enter formula in formula bar:

```
=(A1:A3)*(B1:B3)
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula.

It produces output `1,0,0`. If you want exactly `TRUE/FALSE`, use:

```
=(A1:A3)*(B1:B3)>0
```

also with array entry

[image]

Comment: another thing i like to do is `=1*(A1:A3)*(B1:B3)` as this gives me `1` or `0` which i find much easier to parse visually

Comment: `=(A1:A3)*(B1:B3)` also gives `1` or `0`

Comment: oh, my bad, you're totally right, i was thinking of something else altogether. thanks